# How to rotate a chart 90 degrees including the text values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following progress bar, but I'd like it to go vertically instead of horizontally. In other words, I'd like to flip it 90 degrees and have the text flipped by 90 degrees as well

[image: Progress Bar]

See my code below, as well as my code pen here: 
http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/jPGMzW

How would I rotate this chart as well as the text value?

HTML

```
<!-- Change the below data attribute to play -->
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="50">
  <div class="progress-bar-state progress">50</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap:before {
  content: '66';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap:after {
  content: '$250,000';
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-wrap .progress-bar-state {
  background: #ddd;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Javascript

```
// on page load...
    moveProgressBar();
    // on browser resize...
    $(window).resize(function() {
        moveProgressBar();
    });

    // SIGNATURE PROGRESS
    function moveProgressBar() {
      console.log("moveProgressBar");
        var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
        var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
        var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
        var animationLength = 2500;

        // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
        // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
        $('.progress-bar-state').stop().animate({
            left: progressTotal
        }, animationLength);
    }
```

Comment: You can use css `transform` to rotate your bar, although it seems to break the loading animation: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqJGar](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqJGar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
   .progress {
      height: 500px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .progress-wrap:before {
      content: '66';
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
    .progress-wrap:after {
      content: '$250,000';
      bottom: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
    .progress-wrap {
      background: #f80;
      margin: 20px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    .progress-wrap .progress-bar-state {
      background: #ddd;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
```

Javascript

```
moveProgressBar();
// on browser resize...
$(window).resize(function() {
    moveProgressBar();
});

// SIGNATURE PROGRESS
function moveProgressBar() {
  console.log("moveProgressBar");
    var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
    var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').height();
    var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
    var animationLength = 2500;

    // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
    // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
    $('.progress-bar-state').stop().animate({
        top: progressTotal
    }, animationLength);
}
```

Pretty much its just switching the height and widths as well as the lefts with tops and rights with bottoms.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate text or anything else using this css rule.

```
  transform: rotate(90deg);  /* this is the rotation */
```

Use `-90deg` to rotate the other way.

Comment: I've tried your solution here (http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/BNwpyw), but the issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to fit it within screen. Due to width being at 100%, it scales all the way beyond view, and when I change it to 500px, it's all in view, but then i doesnt work correctly (e.g. when it should be showing 50% it shows more).